# cannot install sqlite3 using gem

Tags: ruby, sqlite, raspberry-pi2, metasploit

I'm trying to install Metasploit on my Raspberry Pi 2.
But when I try to execute this command:

> gem install wirble sqlite3 bundler

I get this error:

> Successfully installed wirble-0.1.3 Parsing documentation for
>   wirble-0.1.3 Done installing documentation for wirble after 2 seconds
>   Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing sqlite3:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
> ```
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13 for inspection. Results logged
>   to
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/arm-linux/2.1.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
>   Successfully installed bundler-1.15.4 Parsing documentation for
>   bundler-1.15.4 Done installing documentation for bundler after 73
>   seconds 2 gems installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is missing ruby dev files. If you are using Debian

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

should do the work.

Install `ruby-dev` using your package managers. (package name may differ across different linux distros)